# Error with clickable area on buttons

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm running Wordpress, WooCommerce and The Retailer (theme) on a webshop for a client. Somehow, the "previous/next" buttons on product pages only have a "active hitbox/clickable area" on the bottom 10-20% of the picture in Chrome and Safari. They work fine in Firefox.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUc95.png

Website: http://www.ment.no/nettbutikk/kopper/gresskopp/

I've tried display:block-inline; and removing padding, but none of them worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `<div class="mobiles_menus_wrapper"></div>` is somehow positioned ontop of the buttons.

If you add `overflow:hidden` to the parent grid_9 it will work in chrome on desktop viewport.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Guess I must have broken it in the process of customizing the theme.